# Does Hibernation save the whole RAM or just what is being used?

Tags: hibernate, 21.04

I have noticed when I hibernate with no open apps it does it faster, than when I have apps open, probably, half the time, I thought that hibernation will save all the memory (RAM) content to the SWAP partition and not only the open apps, please could you help clarify what is going on, thank you
Ubuntu 21.04 - Kernel 5.11

Comment: Whatever is in RAM is saved at the time because hibernation will power off the system which means that anything that is left in RAM will be lost.